# OpenSSL 3 Provider for signature

Tags: nginx, openssl

I've created a basic provider for OpenSSL v3.1.2, that basically looks like:

```
#include <openssl/core_dispatch.h>
#include <openssl/core_names.h>
#include <openssl/params.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

struct rsa_sign_ctx
{
   EVP_PKEY *pkey;
};

static void *rsa_sign_newctx(void *provctx);
static void rsa_sign_freectx(void *ctx);
static int rsa_sign_init(void *ctx, void *provkey);
static int rsa_sign(void *ctx, unsigned char *sig, size_t *siglen, size_t sigsize, const unsigned char *tbs, size_t tbslen);


// here comes basic implementation of the above callback with log printouts
////////////////////

const OSSL_DISPATCH rsa_signature_functions[] = {
  {OSSL_FUNC_SIGNATURE_NEWCTX, (void (*)(void))rsa_sign_newctx},
  {OSSL_FUNC_SIGNATURE_FREECTX, (void (*)(void))rsa_sign_freectx},
  {OSSL_FUNC_SIGNATURE_SIGN_INIT, (void (*)(void))rsa_sign_init},
  {OSSL_FUNC_SIGNATURE_SIGN, (void (*)(void))rsa_sign},
  {0, NULL}};

const OSSL_ALGORITHM my_rsa_algorithm[] = {
  { "RSA", "provider=p_hsmpoc", rsa_signature_functions },
  {NULL, NULL, NULL}};

const OSSL_ALGORITHM *my_provider_query(void *provctx, int operation_id, int *no_cache)
{
   *no_cache = 0;

   switch (operation_id)
   {
   case OSSL_OP_SIGNATURE:
      return my_rsa_algorithm;
   }
   return NULL;
}

const OSSL_DISPATCH my_provider_functions[] = {
   {OSSL_FUNC_PROVIDER_QUERY_OPERATION, (void (*)(void))my_provider_query},
   {0, NULL}};

int OSSL_provider_init(const OSSL_CORE_HANDLE *handle, const OSSL_DISPATCH *in,
                   const OSSL_DISPATCH **out, void **provctx)
{
   *provctx = NULL;
   *out = my_provider_functions;
   return 1;
}
```

After copying the generated SO file to the shared modules dir (for me it's /usr/local/lib64/ossl-modules), updated the openssl.cnf file and running "openssl list -provider <my-prov>" (no errors) I see that the OSSL_provider_init func is called, and when I start the s_server and s_client (using my SSL keypair), I see that the query function my_provider_query is called as expected and register the sign callbacks, but these sign callbacks are not being called as expected during the TLS handshake

Looks like I'm missing some step in the provider setup. Same behavior was when I used Nginx to load the provider.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man7/provider-signature.html, you rsa_sign* functions definitions is outdated. They should be updated to

```
static OSSL_FUNC_signature_newctx_fn rsa_sign_newctx;
static OSSL_FUNC_signature_freectx_fn rsa_sign_freectx;
static OSSL_FUNC_signature_sign_init_fn rsa_sign_init;
static OSSL_FUNC_signature_sign_fn rsa_sign;
```

and implementations for rsa_sign_newctx and rsa_sign_init should be updated accordingly.